# How to add user route to Azure App Services

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure VM with inside custom vpn to 172.254.254.0/24 route.
I am able to reach that VM from another azure VM adding an "user route" to a "route table" in that VM. It works perfectly.
Now I have an Azure App Services web application. 
I need to add the route above too.
But I am stuck I am not able to do it.

Comment: Are these VM's connected to a VNET in azure?  If so, connect the App Service to the same VNET, and it should just work.

Answer (score 0):

Integrate your app with an Azure Virtual Network

The VNet Integration feature has two variations.

1. Regional VNet Integration - When connecting to Resource Manager VNets in the same region, you must have a dedicated subnet in the VNet you are integrating with.
2. Gateway required VNet Integration - When connecting to VNets in other regions or to a Classic VNet in the same region you need a Virtual Network gateway provisioned in the target VNet.

Gateway required VNet Integration only provides access to resources in the target VNet or in networks connected to the target VNet with peering or VPNs. Gateway required VNet Integration doesn't enable access to resources available across ExpressRoute connections or works with service endpoints.

Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#enable-vnet-integration